# It's my book VS It's the book of mine

Tags: pronouns

We can say two sentences:

> 1) It's my book
>
> 2) It's the book of mine

I heard the second variant was moer formal, noble, precise whilst the first one is a standard one. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

> It's the book of mine

Colin Fine says this is grammatical but to me it appears to be nonsense.

If we were having a conversation about a pile of books and somebody said that to me, I would have no idea what they meant.

if they had said **"That book is mine"** I would understand them, and that is more formal than

> It's my book

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but I can't think of many circumstances where anybody would say "It's the book of mine".

All I can come up with is when there are a load of books there (maybe on a shelf), only one of which belongs to you, and you are identifying it to somebody else as the one which belongs to you. This is pretty unlikely, because belonging to you is not normally obvious from looking at the book, so it is probably not an effective way of identifying it.

I suppose that if you are the author, and just one of the books on the shelf has your name on it, then "It's the book of mine" might be an effective way of identifying it.